# Create a class within a table using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm working with entity framework and database for the first time.
I need to save data that it is strictly linked to another one.
The first one is a table of Problem: contains description date and status of the problem,
and the second data is a table of solution : contains a description of solution a date and a status.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6vcup7fw0ahm19/image%20for%20stack%20overflow.png

How can I design this :  A probleme has at least one solution, that means when a user enter a probleme he must enter a solution.
In the same time any other user can add another solution to an existing probleme.

When I add a new controller using the scaffolding option of "MVC Controller with read and write option and Entity framework" I can only find one model for creating the problem and I can't add another model.

I'm extremly sorry for the poor explanation, this whole web development thing is new for me.
Many thanks for your answers

Comment: What have you tried and/or what ideas do you have? What specific issue are you having? The model of this site is to help you, not do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to describe is a one-to-many realtionship. If you haven't done it already, follow one of the great step by step tutorials available on http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials.

There you will definetly get an sufficent explanation on how to approach your problem.

For the sake of this being an answer:

Assuming you have to classes and use the code-first approach.

Your first class is called Problem

```
public class Problem
{
...
}
```

With a second class Solution

```
public class Solution
{
...
}
```

To accomplish a one-to-many relationship you have to implement this in your `problem` class

```
public class Problem
{
...
public virtual ICollection<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
}
```

Translated into English this means: 1 Problem has a collection of Solutions. This collection can be 0 in size or 10 or 20. And there you have it.
This is shown here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I recommend you to start from the beginning though.

Kind regards.